# Module 'smart-table' is not available

Tags: javascript, angularjs, smart-table

I am trying to get started with a smart-table.  I am following the instructions available here: http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/ 
So according to those instructions all I need to do is run, `bower install angular-smart-table` and then add then add the module `angular.module('myApp',['smart-table']` to your angular application.  Here's my angular application:

```
# pwd
/var/www/html
# cat meanVoyApp.js 
var app = angular.module("meanVoyApp", ['smart-table']);
```

But now when I load my markup I get these errors in my browsers console:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module meanVoyApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module smart-table due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'smart-table' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$injector/nomod?p0=smart-table
```

I didn't misspell so I guess I "forgot" to load it.  So how do I load it? How can I tell if it is already loaded and something else is the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you remember to add a reference to the script in your index.html?

```
<script src="[directoryOfModule]/smart-table.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Smart-table comes with some js file. I think you are not loading that before to your meanVoyApp.js load. Use chrome developer tool network panel to identify the java-script are properly loaded nor not.

Use the following code before your app.js load

```
<script src="http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/bower_components/angular-smart-table/dist/smart-table.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
bower install angular-smart-table --save
```

and some good gulp or grunt build tool configuration (e.g. yeoman) will automatically add it to your index.html.

Comment: This helped because in my case bower made some extra work (added lib in assets) which was mandatory, but I had manually add <script src="[dirOfAssets]/smart-table.js"></script> in index.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your build process.

In case you use ngBoilerplate kickstarter, you need to add the following line:
'vendor/angular-smart-table/dist/smart-table.min.js'

inside vendor_files section of build.config.js file.